# bootstrap class is not getting loaded for all rows inside my container

Tags: responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

in my code .col-md-3 is not getting loaded for all rows.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 footer-image col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-3">
        <img alt="Get Started" src="/assets/f_1.png" alt="Life Style" title="life style"
            class="img-thumbnail resize-image"/>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 footer-image col-sm-3 col-xs-2">
        <img alt="Get Started" src="/assets/f_1.png" alt="About Us" title="About Us" 
            class="img-thumbnail resize-image" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 footer-image col-sm-3 col-xs-2">
        <img alt="Get Started" src="/assets/f_1.png" alt="Contact Us" title="Contact Us"
            class="img-thumbnail resize-image" />
    </div>

</div> 
<div class="row">
    <div class='col-md-3'>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae, in, soluta deserunt
    </div>

    <div class='col-md-3'>
        Delectus, earum, nobis, esse expedita corporis eaque cupiditate nihil quia consequuntur ea 
    </div>

    <div class='col-md-3'>
        Delectus, quam, minus quisquam fugit harum a ab quo fugiat obcaecati molestias voluptatem velit 
    </div>
</div>
```

In the first row section, where I am adding images, there the col-md-3 is getting loaded, but the same is not getting loaded in next row(with text contents) !

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

is this what you're trying to achieve? Try reconstructing your .cols again without the offsets.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, tempore, blanditiis ab consequuntur ea molestiae?</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui, quis libero cupiditate repellat iusto voluptatum.</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus, assumenda, aspernatur nihil ut quia eveniet!</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus, assumenda, aspernatur nihil ut quia eveniet!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: bang. my code is all correct. anyway i need offset in first row so can't remove it. just restarted my system and it's working as usual. ;(